# Kendo UI templates formatting

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, globalization, kendo-scheduler, kendo-template

My Kendo Scheduler uses predefined HTML template, where I have this field:

```
<input type="text" data-type="date" data-role="datetimepicker" data-bind="value:start,visible:isAllDay" name="start" data-validate="true"/>
```

This field showing some datetime. Problem is that I can't (or actually don't know how to) format displayed datetime according to [this article](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/globalization/dateformatting).
How i can solve this?

---

UPD: Yes, I know about `data-format`, but it doesn't works everywhere. 
Please see the picture attached — in this example, formatting via `date-format` works for field, but not works for time selector ( `datarole="datetimeselector"` ).
[image: time selector don't recognize format]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you tried setting the [`format`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/datepicker#configuration-format) paramenter as a [data attribute](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/data-attribute-initialization#configuration)?

```
<input type="text" data-format="g" data-type="date" data-role="datepicker" data-bind="value:start,visible:isAllDay" name="start" data-validate="true"/>
```

If that doesn't works, you can always intercept you data(I presume it is remote) with [`schema.parse`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-schema.parse):

```
dataSource: 
{
    schema: 
    {
        parse: function(data) 
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
            {
                data[i].start = kendo.toString(start, "g");
            }

            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

Not the best way but sometimes it is needed.

Comment: Thanks and sorry. Updated question.

Comment: @ArmanHayots ok but post the case that doesn't works, in this case the field with *DateTime*  widget.

Comment: Sorry again. This is my fault.

Comment: Any idea of the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30156110/legend-customization